# What is an infrared quantum counter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, laser, particle-detectors

What is an infrared quantum counter?

Please explain this like you were telling it to an undergrad - I haven't taken quantum yet but I took modern physics.

I've googled, YouTubed, etc the closest I found was an analogy with a REM detector? So are we saying this just detects infrared light? Why isn't this called a detector? What is the difference between counter and detector? Which one is "better"?

Comment: I've been in experimental quantum mechanics since 2007 and I've never heard of an "infrared quantum counter". Can you please provide a link to a source where you saw this phrase?

Comment: @DanielSank  still google has it . example https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-7-10-2053

Answer (score 2):

Searching, I learned the following:

> Quantum  counting with up-conversion of infrared
> radiation to visible light has been proposed by Bloembergen and was  realized for the near infrared utilizing the energy levels  of  rare-earth ions in various crystals.  Radiation of an $H_2O$  laser at a  wavelength of 28 $μm$
> was detected using exciton levels in $CdS$  for  quantum -counter action.

The file can be downloaded [from here.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2967832_Quantum_Counter_for_FarInfrared_Radiation)

In order to detect infrared radiation it is converted , photon by photon with the interactions described into visible light.

A counter counts, a detector detects. A counter is a detector and gives more details than a detector. A detector can be many other options than a counter.